# Essential range of a function is closed

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I've seen a couple of questions regarding compactness of the essential range of a function $f \in L^{\infty}$, but everyone seems to know that $R_{f}$ is closed. I'm pretty sure that I'm missing out on something really basic. Any help would be appreciated!

Edited : the precise definition of the essential range is given as

$$\text{the set of all} \quad z \in \mathbb{C} \quad \text{such that} \quad \{x : |f(x)-z| > \epsilon \}\quad \text{has positive measure for all}\quad \epsilon>0$$

Comment: How to prove this will depend on your exact definition of the essential range, which you should therefore provide. In most likelihood, the argument can be made in terms of closure points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\left(z_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of elements of $R_f$ that converges to some $z$.
Let $\varepsilon_0\gt 0$ be fixed. Pick $n_0$ such that $\left\lvert z_{n_0}-z\right\rvert\lt\varepsilon_0/2$. Then use the inclusion
$$\left\{x: \left\lvert f(x)-z\right\rvert\gt \varepsilon_0/2\right\}\supset\left\{x: \left\lvert f(x)-z_{n_0}\right\rvert\gt \varepsilon_0 \right\}.$$